# Finding Average Time Length in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[image]

I am a beginner in SQL and I am using Big Query. I am looking to find the average length of time.

My columns are in the image.

Can someone please tell me how to write a query to find the average time for the column `ride_length` in minutes? The ride_length column is in `h:mm` format.

Comment: What if the duration is less than 1 hour? Will you have `0` hours? Like `00:59`.

Comment: Yes. If the time duration was 30 minutes for example. It would be 0:30.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(
        CAST( SPLIT( ride_length, ':' )[OFFSET(1)] AS NUMERIC )
        + CAST( SPLIT( ride_length, ':' )[OFFSET(0)] AS NUMERIC ) * 60 
    )
FROM TheTable
```

`SPLIT` is used to separate hours from minutes and then each result converted (`CAST`) to NUMBER.

[I did **not** test it]

Here is the data verification query (untested as well) to check on format consistency:

```
SELECT
  ride_id,
  ride_length
 WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(ride_length, r'^(\d+\:\d+)$)';
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Using your query I get 'Syntax error: Unexpected ")" at [4:53]'

Comment: Can you please try now?

Comment: I now get this error. 'No matching signature for operator * for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signatures: INT64 * INT64; FLOAT64 * FLOAT64; NUMERIC * NUMERIC; BIGNUMERIC * BIGNUMERIC; INTERVAL * INT64; INT64 * INTERVAL at [3:17]'

Comment: Yes, I did multiplication to convert hours to minutes *before* casting to a number. I fixed it now.

Comment: It now says the Query will run but when I try to run it I get 'Array index 1 is out of bounds (overflow)'

Comment: Thank you for all of your help btw. I really appreciate it.

Comment: `Index 1` is minutes.  Your data might be is not entirely in the format you described.  Please make sure that **all** your values follow the pattern: **1 or 2 digits followed by `:` followed by 1 or 2 digits**.  For example you should not have `12` or `12:`  - you should have `12:0` or `12:00` instead.

Comment: I added a query that should (hopefully) test my theory about data format inconsistency.